# nested loops and conditional checks in list comprehensions (python)

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm currenty learning list comprehension in Python and I want to write a function that takes two lists, `a` and `b`, and returns all elements of `a` that are divisible by all elements of `b`.

The equivalent of this (not using list comprehension) would be:

```
    a = [10, 5]
    b = [5, 2]
    c = []
    d = True
    for i in a:
        for j in b:
            if i % j != 0:
                d = False
        if d:
            c.append(i)
    return c
```

How can I do this with list comprehension?
I currently have `[x for x in a for y in b if x % y == 0]` but that only requires x to match one of the items in b, not all of them.

Comment: Use `all(...)` or `any(...)`.

Comment: oh yeah, I totally forgot about that. thanks for the help

Comment: do `[x for x in a if all(i for i in b if x % i == 0)]`

Comment: And fix your above code. If you add `20` at the end of `a`, it won't get into `c`.

Comment: @YOLO Your example is not working correctly

Comment: When you get a satisfying answer you might want to mark it as accepted with the green tick mark. You can always change your accepted answer if better options come along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
a = [10, 5]
b = [5, 2]

res = [x for x in a if all(x % y == 0 for y in b)]
```

for completion on @superb rain 's comment. Here is also an example for any(...):

```
res = [x for x in a if not any(x % y != 0 for y in b)]
```

Comment: You don't need the `!= 0`.

Comment: You are right, but it is easier to understand if you compare both.

Comment: Meh, I guess, if you want that. But I read `not any(x % d for d in b)` as "not any remainders (when dividing by elements from b)" and find that somewhat more elegant.

Comment: Thats okay for me.